# How to renumber primary index

Tags: sql, mysql

I have got a simple MySQL table and primary index (id) is not numbered one by one (1, 31, 35, 100 etc.). I want them to be numbered like (1, 2, 3, 4). Please tell me how to do it. I would also like to point that I am aware of possible consequences of the operation, but I just want to tidy up the table.

Comment: No, you aren't aware of consequences. "Tidying up" a primary key is a **horrible** idea that will break relations between tables.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I agree other methods will work but I'm just giving a different idea. This will do without any temp table creation requirements::

```
SET @i=0;
UPDATE table_name SET column_name=(@i:=@i+1);
```

Comment: It will not reset the auto_increment value, so if your auto_increment was at 1344 and after updating you only get id 100 the next row will have the id 1344, creating a hole again. Ofc it's possible to set the auto_increment manually after updating.

Comment: oFcourse you have to update auto increment; I missed specifying that.

ALTER TABLE TABLENAME auto_increment = <value of @a>;

Comment: Yah , this is great, but one thing to consider : duplicate id

Comment: Is this guaranteed to preserve the order of the records of the original table? The individual records of the table could be updated in an arbitrary order, right? So ordering is not neccessarily preserved, I suppose. Maybe you should append `ORDER BY column_name`.

Answer (score 20):

give a try to renumber method of dalmp ([DALMP Database Abstraction Layer for MySQL using PHP.](http://dalmp.readthedocs.org/en/latest/database/renumber.html))

```
$db->renumber('table','uid');
```

basically it does this:

```
SET @var_name = 0;
UPDATE Tablename SET ID = (@var_name := @var_name +1);
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

Comment: Fantastic @tareco, this is perfect for a different but similar problem when you want to import records from an sql dump into a table and find conflicting primary key values.  I ran your sql command on my target table before the import and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest Solution is:

- Rename the table to tablename_temp
- Create a new table with the old name and the same structure
- INSERT INTO tablename (id, field1, field2, field3) SELECT NULL, field1, field2, field3, ... FROM tablename_temp;
- DROP tablename_temp

This will destroy all of your data if you are using foreign keys and i strongly suggest you leave the ids as they are. A Database is not untidy because the primary keys are not in sequence, a Database is untidy if it's referential integrity (id values pointing to the wrong or non-existant row in other tables) is broken.

Comment: I just duplicate the table, delete the auto-increment ID column in the new table, save that table, then add a new ID auto-increment column. As you say, where foreign keys are involved, this can be a lot more complicated. Fortunately, I only have to do this with log tables.

Answer (score 4):

1. Delete the "id" column.
2. Create column named id with auto increment on(and do not allow nulls), it will have the new values you want.
3. Assign this new "id" column as PK.

edited later thanks to comments.

Comment: you can only have one auto increment column at once, so if you wanna follow this recipe, you can just do a short cut: 1. delete the old column. 2. make a new one.

Answer (score 3):

```
CREATE TABLE newtable 
  LIKE oldtable 
  SELECT NULL, col1, col2, col3, etc FROM oldtable;
```

Without including the primary key column in the select, but all the other columns.

And the primary key column should be first in the table, or you'll need to set the `NULL` to the position of the primary key column. And the column should have a "NOT NULL" setting. Otherwise it will just be set as null, and that's kind of pointless.

The reason this works is because MySQL likes to ignore NULL inserts on auto_increments, and instead create a new number for it (provided that null isn't a valid value on that column).

Comment: Mysql: CREATE TABLE newtable as SELECT * FROM oldtable;

Comment: @DanielKatz that will also copy the old primary key values.

Comment: Ah ok, I was more concerned about the AS rather then LIKE

Comment: @DanielKatz The LIKE is a create table construct to copy another. AS is an alias. You wouldn't get any of the constraints in your AS table, just the data, whereas in the LIKE you duplicate the constraints as well. I think

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to renumber it. Primary key **is not a number.** It's just a black box unique identifier, that only resembles a continuous sequence. In reality you'll never have it intact, so you shouldn't bother making it "nice". While the only purpose of a primary key is to stick with database row forever, making it possible to reference rows from other tables.

Any prettifying such as adding cute numbers should be added with output only. Especially given the table may be ordered in thousands different ways.

Wanting to renumber the primary key is a typical newbie mistake, and it's a  great pity that Stack Overflow endorses it with all those servile answers.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. How this ID is king! is related to the problem? Probably you need to read the entire sentence, not just a single word meaningless. though I must admit, the word choice is not the best.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the auto-increment on your primary key (if it is a primary key)

Here's a link:

[sql autoincrement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Comment: -1: This does not answer the question. If you delete i.e. the row with the autoincremented value 2 then you have a hole in the ids. That is what he wants to change.

Comment: But you cannot prevent the wholes as you allow deleting your records. So creating a new table will help just temporally

Answer (score 0):

dump to datafile and reimport might work somehow

```
mysqldump db table |sed s/// > outfile.sql
```

then reimport

Comment: "Might work somehow" does not read like an answer according to [answer].