# I need to "reset" identity column ex.(1,3,8) to (1,2,3)

Tags: t-sql, identity, reset, sql-server-2017

I was asked to reset the Auto_Increment (identity) column in this way:+
Auto_Increment(1,3,8,10) to this New_Auto_Increment (1,2,3,4).I don't want to drop the column and rebuild because it can cause serious problems. Thanks

Comment: So you just want to change the existing identity values?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to renumber primary index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643371/how-to-renumber-primary-index)

Comment: Auto increment (Identity) column values should have no business meaning. The only requirements one should have from such a column is that the database should auto-fill it. It doesn't need to nor does it guarantee to have no gaps, to be inserted in a specific order (well, it you wouldn't temper with it, then it will be in a specific order, but if someone will reseed it then you have a problem), or to have no gaps. If the data in the column have a busyness meaning, then it should not be an identity column in the first place.

Comment: You didn't ask a question, but the answer is "No." Deliver that to whoever asked you to update the column. (Good thing there aren't any foreign key references to the column!)

Comment: @DanGuzman hes but i try to find a possible solution without make a temp table or delete and rebuild all the rows. Is there as way to just to update the values only in identity column?

Comment: @DanGuzman thanks btw for help

Answer (score 1):

One method to assign new `IDENTITY` values is by loading a staging table with the new values and then using `SWITCH` to move the new data back into the source table. If foreign keys reference the table, those will need to be dropped and recreated (and the referencing key values updated). Sample script below.

```
--example setup
CREATE TABLE dbo.Example(
      ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_Example PRIMARY KEY
    , SomeData int
    );
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Example ON;
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Example(ID, SomeData) VALUES (1,1),(3,1),(8,1),(10,1);
GO

BEGIN TRY

    BEGIN TRAN;

    --create staging table with same schema, constraints and indexes
    CREATE TABLE dbo.ExampleStaging(
          ID int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_Example_ExampleStaging PRIMARY KEY
        , SomeData int
        );

    --load staging table with new values
    INSERT INTO dbo.ExampleStaging
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID), SomeData
        FROM dbo.Example;

    --clear source table
    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.Example;

    --switch new data back into original table
    ALTER TABLE dbo.ExampleStaging
        SWITCH TO dbo.Example;

    DROP TABLE dbo.ExampleStaging;

    DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.Example');

    COMMIT;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
GO
```

One could also drop and recreate the column to reassign identity values. The implications with that method are:

1) Indexes (e.g. primary key constraint) on the column would need to be first dropped and recreated. In the case of a the clustered index, all non-clustered indexes on the table would be implicitly rebuilt twice, once when the clustered index is dropped and again when recreated. However, one could explicitly drop and recreate non-clustered indexes so that only happens once.

2) The new identity values would not be in the same incremental sequence as the original values. This might be a non-issue unless one expects the values to reflect order of insertion.

3) Each row in the table would need to be updated twice, once when the original identity column is dropped and again when the new one created.

Comment: Nice! but wouldn't it be easier to just drop and re-create the identity column?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, the column drop/create would require updating every row twice and would not preserve the existing temporal incremental order (assuming that's desired).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I improved my answer to answer your question as well. Thanks for asking!

Comment: @DanGuzman See my answer.  Can do it with row_number() and a cursor.

Comment: that works! but what if the "user" input the table name so i don't know the tables columns, how can i use this  INSERT INTO dbo.ExampleStaging
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID), SomeData
        FROM dbo.Example;

Comment: (continue ) i can reseed to 0 after this and have to copy the other columns except id so the id can be applied automatic. The problem is how to select them!

Comment: @Dionysis, I don't know what you mean about not knowing the table columns. The script I provided will reseed the next value. If you reseed at 0, you'll get duplicates when new rows are inserted.

Comment: @Dionysis Have you tried my solution.   It fixes the table in place.

Answer (score 0):

Can do it with row_number() and a cursor
And could even clean up any FKs

```
drop table #T;
set nocount on;
create table #T (pk int identity primary key, val int);
insert into #T(val) values (2), (5), (11), (3), (7), (2), (5), (11), (3), (7);
delete t from #T t where t.val in (5, 7);
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by t.pk) as rn 
from #T t 
order by t.pk;

declare @val int, @pk int, @rn int;
set identity_insert #T on;
DECLARE csr CURSOR FOR   
    select t.pk, t.val, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by t.pk) as rn 
    from #T t 
    order by t.pk;
    OPEN csr 
    FETCH NEXT FROM csr   
    INTO  @pk, @val, @rn;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN
        --select @pk as pk,  @val as val, @rn as rn         
        if(@pk <> @rn)
        begin
          insert into #T(pk, val) values (@rn, @val);
          delete #T where pk = @pk;
        end
        FETCH NEXT FROM csr   
        INTO  @pk, @val, @rn;
    END
    CLOSE csr;  
DEALLOCATE csr;
set identity_insert #T off;
select * 
from #T t 
order by t.pk;
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('#T', RESEED, @rn);
insert into #T(val) values (77);
select * 
from #T t 
order by t.pk;
drop table #t;
```

Comment: the fact that is working in place is very good for me! My professor still think that i have to change only the identity column without drop , but i saw that is not possible. Thank you very much!!!( now i have to learn how cursor works :P)