# Update single column of table and value should start from 0 and then should increment by 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-variables

```
$sqlcount1 ="SET uid = -1 UPDATE `agent_normal` SET `uid` = @a:=@a+1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlcount1);
```

how to write this query in core php?

This query works in mysql but not in core php.

Here i want to update a single row of table and value should start from 0 and then should increment by 1.

Comment: The code above **is** core PHP. Please clarify exactly what it is you're trying to do and what problems you're encountering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to renumber primary index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643371/how-to-renumber-primary-index)

Comment: @Mike this query doesnt work in core php but works in phpmyadmin.

Comment: @Nick yes both the queries are same but how do i use it in core php???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems. Firstly, if you look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643371/how-to-renumber-primary-index) you'll see you have an incorrect variable name and missing semicolon. The query should be :

```
$sqlcount1 ="SET @a = -1; UPDATE `agent_normal` SET `uid` = @a:=@a+1";
```

Secondly, to use two queries in one call you need to use [mysqli_multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

```
$result = mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sqlcount1);
```