# How to do auto increment after delete the query(/row) in a PHP file?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Statement**

I want to do auto_increment after deleting the query without setting auto_increment in MySQL Workbench every time after I delete the query.

(I know only how to delete the last row.)

So I want to do it if I delete any row in the MySQL server in a php file.

In the table, it contained `ID` is PK, UNIQUE and auto_increment. (First column)

**Code**

This part of code works only if delete the last query.
(BUT HOW TO DO IF I TRY TO DELETE FIRST ROW OR MIDDLE ROW)

```
$conn->query("ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=1;");
```

**Sample table** (name "tablename")

```
---------------------
| ID(PK)| A | B | C |
--------+---+---+----
|   1   |   |   |   | 
|   2   |   |   |   |
|   3   |   |   |   |
|   4   |   |   |   |
|   .   |   |   |   |
|   .   |   |   |   | 
|   .   |   |   |   |
|   50  |   |   |   |
---------------------
```

Form the sample table above, there two cases that I would like to expect.

*Notes* - Delete the last row is not a problem.

**1.** If I delete `num_row 1`

**2.** If I delete `num_row >1 && num_row < 50`

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Do you *need* the id values to be sequential for some reason?

Comment: Ofc, I need ID value as well the row values to be sequential for some reason. The reason is I don't want to type `ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=1;` or reconfigure the table on MySQL Workbench after I delete any row every time. @Nick

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643371/how-to-renumber-primary-index