# How to make the delete button show and do action on only last row of the table?

Tags: php, html

**Statement**

After I faced a problem about deleting the query if the row is not the last one.

Here is my eariler post : [How to do auto increment after delete the query(/row) in a PHP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55624661/how-to-do-auto-increment-after-delete-the-query-row-in-a-php-file)

So I came up with a new idea to prevent the problem which I would like to show delete button and do delete action on only the last row of the query.

**What I know**

As far as I know that if I would like to delete the last row in the PHP file.

We can do like this -> `$conn->query("ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT=1;");`

**show.php** (Only table part)

```
<!--Table-->
    <div class="container">
         <table class="table table-hover" border='2' align='center' style='color: white'>
                        <!--Header-->
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><center>ID</center></th>
                            <th><center>Type</center></th>
                            <th><center>URL</center></th>
                            <th><center>Date</center></th>
                            <th><center>Lattitude</center></th>
                            <th><center>Longitude</center></th>
                            <th colspan="2"><center>Action</center></th>
                       </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <!--Queries-->
                       <?php
                            for($i=0;$i<count($results->data);$i++):
                                $news = $results->data[$i];
                       ?>
                                <tr>
                                      <td><b><?php echo $news['crimenews_id'];?></b></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_cat'];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_url'];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_datetime'];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_locationLat'];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_locationLong'];?></td>
                                      <td>
                                           <a href="front.php?Edit=<?php echo $news['crimenews_id'];?>" class="btn btn-light"><b>Edit &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i class="far fa-edit"></i></b></a>

                                           <!--Do I need if-else statement to if it is last row or not?-->
                                           <a href="process.php?Delete=<?php echo $news['crimenews_id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger"><b>Delete <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></b></a> <!--Delete button here!-->
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                            <?php endfor ?>
                    </table>
         </div>
<!--End table-->
```

**delete.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['Delete']))
      {
          $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']);
          $del = $_GET['Delete'];
          //$conn->query("DELETE FROM crimenews WHERE crimenews_id=$del");

          $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM crimenews WHERE crimenews_id=$del");
          $stmt->bind_param("sssss",$SESSION['crimenews_id']);
          $stmt->execute();

          //Delete only last row
          //$conn->query("ALTER TABLE crimenews AUTO_INCREMENT=1;");

          $_SESSION['message'] = "The news has deleted.";
          $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";
          $stmt->close();
          header("location: front.php");
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add **if else** to hide or display your **`Delete Button`**:

```
<!--Table-->
    <div class="container">
         <table class="table table-hover" border='2' align='center' style='color: white'>
                        <!--Header-->
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><center>ID</center></th>
                            <th><center>Type</center></th>
                            <th><center>URL</center></th>
                            <th><center>Date</center></th>
                            <th><center>Lattitude</center></th>
                            <th><center>Longitude</center></th>
                            <th colspan="2"><center>Action</center></th>
                       </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <!--Queries-->
                       <?php
                            //$rowCount = count($results->data); //or mysqli_num_rows($results)
                            for($i=0;$i<count($results->data);$i++):
                                $news = $results->data[$i];
                       ?>
                                <tr>
                                      <td><b><?php echo $news['crimenews_id'];?></b></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_cat'];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_url'];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_datetime'];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_locationLat'];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_locationLong'];?></td>
                                      <td>
                                           <a href="front.php?Edit=<?php echo $news['crimenews_id'];?>" class="btn btn-light"><b>Edit &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i class="far fa-edit"></i></b></a>

                                           <!--Do I need if-else statement to if it is last row or not?-->
                                           <?php
                                           if($i===(count($results->data)-1)){?>
                                              <a href="process.php?Delete=<?php echo $news['crimenews_id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger"><b>Delete <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></b></a> <!--Delete button here!-->

                                           <?php }?>
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                            <?php endfor ?>
                    </table>
         </div>
<!--End table-->
```

In the above code, you check if iteration is equal to the last count of row result.
Check it. I hope it helps

Comment: Do I have to change anything in `delete.php`? or just modify only in `show.php`

Comment: I already added it but the delete button didn't show up in the last row.

Comment: did you try the or part `//or mysqli_num_rows($results)`

Comment: **Error** `Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, object given` --> There is sth wrong in `mysqli_num_rows($results);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191642/discussion-between-fmsthird-and-o-san).

Answer (score 0):

Change show.php with below code in order to show the delete button only on last row

```
<!--Table-->
    <div class="container">
         <table class="table table-hover" border='2' align='center' style='color: white'>
                        <!--Header-->
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th><center>ID</center></th>
                            <th><center>Type</center></th>
                            <th><center>URL</center></th>
                            <th><center>Date</center></th>
                            <th><center>Lattitude</center></th>
                            <th><center>Longitude</center></th>
                            <th colspan="2"><center>Action</center></th>
                       </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <!--Queries-->
                       <?php
                            for($i=0;$i<count($results->data);$i++):
                                $news = $results->data[$i];
                       ?>
                                <tr>
                                      <td><b><?php echo $news['crimenews_id'];?></b></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_cat'];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_url'];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_datetime'];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_locationLat'];?></td>
                                      <td><?php echo $news['crimenews_locationLong'];?></td>
                                      <td>
                                           <a href="front.php?Edit=<?php echo $news['crimenews_id'];?>" class="btn btn-light"><b>Edit &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<i class="far fa-edit"></i></b></a>
                                           <?php if($i==(count($results->data)-1)){ ?>
                                           <a href="delete.php?Delete=<?php echo $news['crimenews_id'];?>" class="btn btn-danger"><b>Delete <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></b></a> <!-- your file is delete.php not process.php -->
                                           <?php } ?>
                                      </td>
                                  </tr>
                            <?php endfor ?>
                    </table>
         </div>
<!--End table-->
```

And in delete.php do the following changes. Details of changes in the comments

```
if(isset($_GET['Delete']))
      {
          // $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']); this is not needed and will through an error as $_POST['id'] is not set
          $del = $_GET['Delete'];
          $stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM crimenews WHERE crimenews_id=?"); //change $del to ?
          $stmt->bind_param("i",$del); //change ssss to i as I guess the id is an int and bind the correct parameter
          if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $_SESSION['message'] = "The news has deleted.";
            $_SESSION['msg_type'] = "danger";
            $stmt->close();
            header("location: front.php");
          }
      }
```