# Get new autoincremented value to selected cells

Tags: mysql

Accidentally imported values to an id column which is set to be auto increment. Having lots of duplicated, tried to reset those ids to table's autoincrement value:

```
update tableccc set id=(SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "mydb"
AND TABLE_NAME = "tableccc") where id<1700
```

but now I have the same value for each id

how can I add the auto incremented value to those id cells?
[image]

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643371/how-to-renumber-primary-index

Answer (score 0):

At first save in a var the max id in this way you will avoid duplicated records

```
SET @id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableccc );
```

Then update all records with id 146293 (duplicated id)

```
UPDATE tableccc SET id=(@id:=@id+1) WHERE id =146293 ;
```

finally update auto incremt for 'tableccc'

```
UPDATE information_schema.TABLES
 SET AUTO_INCREMENT = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableccc )
 WHERE 
          TABLE_SCHEMA = "mydb"
      AND TABLE_NAME = 'tableccc';
```