# How to update field all rows using auto increment?

Tags: mysql

How to update field all rows using auto increment?

I need to update field `num` from 1 to count of rows. How to apply AUTO INCREMENT for update operation?

I have tied:

```
UPDATE table set num = (select num from table order by num limit 1) + 1;
```

Comment: You want to update `num` in every row of the table to the same value?

Comment: To next value from 0 to rows.length

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643371/how-to-renumber-primary-index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is esentially join a rownumber to the every row and update the num column
with it

For the join part you need a unique identifier in the example it is id

```
UPDATE table AS t
JOIN
(
    SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, id
    FROM table 
    , (select @rownum := 0) rn
) AS r ON t.id = r.id
SET t.num = r.rownum
```