# How to renumber primary index of a table using spring annotation?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot project which uses MySQL database. I have a table called Employee it has a primary index (id) is not numbered one by one (1, 31, 35, 100 etc.). I want them to be numbered like (1, 2, 3, 4)

there is also similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643371/how-to-renumber-primary-index)

I got the query form above link `SET @i=0; UPDATE Employee SET id=(@i:=@i+1);` and it is working fine if execute it directly in MySQL workbench

my question is how can I execute the above query using the spring annotation?

EmployeeRepository.java

```
public interface EmployeeRepositoryextends JpaRepository<Employee, Integer> {
    
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "SET @i=0; UPDATE Employee e SET e.id=(@i:=@i+1)", nativeQuery = true)
    public void renumberingId();    
}
```

EmployeeService.java

```
   @Service
   public class EmployeeService {

        @Autowired
        private EmployeeRepository repo;
        
        public void renumber() {
             repo.renumberingId();
        }
   }
```

When test the `renumber()` method using junit it gives me the below exception

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':' [SET @i=0; UPDATE Employee e SET e.id=(@i:=@i+1)];
```

please help how can execute this query `SET @i=0; UPDATE Employee SET id=(@i:=@i+1);` using `renumberingId()` method

Comment: you don't. it is numbered 1, 2, 3, ... but elements in between have been deleted. If you start altering that, it becomes pointless to use indices at all.

Comment: *I have a table called Employee it has a primary index (id) is not numbered one by one (1, 31, 35, 100 etc.). I want them to be numbered like (1, 2, 3, 4)* Do this NEVER. If you need in static adjacent enumeration then simply create one more column in the table and enumerate rows in it, if you need in dynamic enumeration then do it in retrieving query.

Comment: The primary index uniquely identifies a row for the entire lifetime of the table. Pay attention - table, not row. In other words, even if a row is deleted, it is not a reason to assign its primary key value to another or newly inserted row.

Comment: @Akina can you plz help me how can I enumerate(static adjacent) the other column?

Comment: Your queries set `SET @i=0; UPDATE Employee e SET e.id=(@i:=@i+1)` is correct. Simply alter it slightly - move variable initialization into UPDATE: `UPDATE Employee e, (SELECT @i:=0) var SET e.new_column =(@i:=@i+1);`

Comment: @Akina your query working fine in MySQL workbench. the problem is that the @Query() annotation always search for a parameter after : but here we are given raw value while assigning new_column to  e.new_column =(@i:=@i+1 and it gives org.hibernate.QueryException: Space is not allowed after parameter prefix ':'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Your queries set `SET @i=0; UPDATE Employee e SET e.id=(@i:=@i+1)` is correct. Simply alter it slightly - move variable initialization into UPDATE: `UPDATE Employee e, (SELECT @i:=0) var SET e.new_column =(@i:=@i+1);`

> your query working fine in MySQL workbench. the problem is that the @Query() annotation always search for a parameter after `:`

If so you may fill new column with enumeration by

```sql
UPDATE Employee t0
  JOIN ( SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t2.id) cnt
         FROM Employee t1
         JOIN Employee t2 ON t1.id >= t2.id
         GROUP BY t1.id ) t3 ON t0.id = t3.id
SET t0.new_column = t3.cnt;
```

[modelling fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e38cb9e3527259022f85adaadadd9dd)

Comment: I could not understood your query but is working fine and this the best answer yet thank a lot (:

Comment: @MohammadRahimTaheri *I could not understood your query* it is simple. See inner SELECT subquery - for each `id` it calculates how many values there is in the table which are less or equal. This amount is by fact the row number. Then this calculated number is stored into the table by outer UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all this for that, this is how it is done :

```
import javax.persistance.*;

@Entity   
public class Employee {   

  @Id   
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
  public long id;

}
```

And it should automacaly do what you are expecting

Comment: thanks for your answer it does not renumbering the id after deleting a row from Employee table

Comment: @MohammadRahimTaheri NEVER even think of attempting to renumber id's. your business logic will have several objects with an equal id, and have known id's that are no longer valid. there is a reason this can't be easily done.