# MariaDB ROW_NUMBER() equivalent in MariaDB 5.2

Tags: mariadb, row, calculated-columns, 32-bit, row-number

I am using Windows 32-bit so the most recent version of MariaDB I can use is 5.2. My question is, how do I have a calculated column that shows the current row number of the field?

As an example, I can create a calculated column with this:

`UPDATE myTable SET myCalculatedColumn = some_other_column/2;`

But how do I get the row number?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/228654/230539

Comment: Do you mean row number over the entire table, or for a specific set of rows?

Comment: i want each cell in a column to say what row number that cell is in. I commented a link that has the answer

Comment: now im trying to find out how to get the total number of rows and shove it in the row calculation equation thats in that link

Comment: Why do you need the total number of rows? Anyway, perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643371/how-to-renumber-primary-index

Comment: thats cool thanks. Im trying to get the total number of rows for another calculation I need.

Comment: I cant put count(*) in an equation

Comment: There are still downloads of 32bit MariaDB server on Windows as of 10.6 beta, and all the way from 5.1 to 10.5, so the most recent GA version you can use is 10.5, and beta 10.6. If you're on Windows XP, then it is a different story

Comment: It says it's only supported on Windows 10 and windows server.